# Assembly language carry flag counter

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to do my assignment which is making loops and right now I'm stuck on righting a loop for a carry flag counter. Here's the requirement:

"place the value 1 into the register eax and shift left until the carry flag is set, keeping a counter of how many times the shift is done."

So I don't understand how this is done. Everything I've done so far ended up with a negative number. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong?

```
        mov     eax, 1
 Loop3:
        shl     eax, 1
        cmp     eax, 0
        jnz     Loop3
        mov     eax, counter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is the following thing:

```
    mov eax, 1
    mov ecx, 0
Loop3:
    inc ecx
    shl eax, 1
    jnc Loop3
    mov counter, ecx
```

Comment: `xor ecx, ecx` is equivalent to `mov ecx, 0` and two bytes shorter. Just my 2 cents.